# Debugging service crashes

Tags: android, debugging, service, crash-reports

I have a music service that takes care of music playback in the background of course, and also a few other things such as notifying activities of UI changes that need to be made, storing and restoring queues, obtaining song records via a cursor, and every time the song changes it takes care of updating the bitmap on the ongoing notification.

**What is the problem?** The service **crashes** almost all the time the user tries to do..well pretty much anything else. For instance, playing a song, and then opening a game crashes the service, sometimes light things like browsing the web on chrome will crash it too.

A few details:

**1 -** The service is started via `startService(new Intent(this, MyMusicService.class));`  but when user leaves activity I call `startForeground(mId, mNotification);` to show an ongoing notification that provides easy controls, and also because `startForeground()` is intented for services that should be prioritized as the killing of these by the activityManager would be disruptive for the user experience (music is stopped if service is killed)

**2 -** I have attempted to reproduce the crash, and it certainly happens when doing not so heavy work, like browsing on chrome (this would reproduce the crash almost 50% of the time), and **always** when doing things like launching temple run 2. FYI, if not doing anything at all - just playing music on the background and idle, playback will **not** stop at all, and it is works just the way it's intended to.

**3 -** The phone I am using as test device is not by any means a slow or low-memory device, it is a Galaxy Nexus.

**4 -** I've tried catching a few longs and sometimes it simply says:

```
02-24 06:53:32.586: I/ActivityManager(387): Process com.deadpixels.light.player (pid 27720) has died.
```

without any other messages, and sometimes the same message is accompanied by a WINDEATH:

```
 02-24 06:53:32.586: W/ActivityManager(387): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.deadpixels.light.player/.service.MyMusicService in 5000ms
 02-24 06:53:32.602: W/InputDispatcher(387): channel '418d09c8    com.deadpixels.light.player/com.deadpixels.light.player.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
 02-24 06:53:32.602: E/InputDispatcher(387): channel '418d09c8 com.deadpixels.light.player/com.deadpixels.light.player.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
 02-24 06:53:32.602: W/InputDispatcher(387): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '418d09c8 com.deadpixels.light.player/com.deadpixels.light.player.HomeActivity (server)'
 02-24 06:53:32.602: I/WindowState(387): WIN DEATH: Window{418d09c8 u0 com.deadpixels.light.player/com.deadpixels.light.player.HomeActivity}
```

What I've also noticed is that almost always when the crash happens, a lot of other services "**die**". I am attaching the full log [here](http://db.tt/P2BOgBlL).

**5 -** I tried using [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) to get more information about the crash but even though everything seems to be setup correctly, after crashing the log is not being sent, or just nothing happens. I know ACRA detects the crash and starts:

```
02-24 06:53:37.719: D/ACRA(28293): ACRA is enabled for com.deadpixels.light.player, intializing...
02-24 06:53:37.742: D/ACRA(28293): Using default Mail Report Fields
02-24 06:53:37.742: D/ACRA(28293): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.deadpixels.light.player/files
02-24 06:53:37.742: W/ACRA(28293): com.deadpixels.light.player reports will be sent by email (if accepted by user).
```

but nothing is being sent, neither to the mailto I set, or to the form in Google docs.

Not sure what else to try, and I was hoping to get some good ideas on what to look for. As I said, the service does do a few things, that to my knowledge are not that resource-extensive, and to be honest, I am not even sure if it is anything to do with the service that's crashing.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/daniel-c05/308d878b5539933f6541) of several code bits that take place in the service, and also the ACRA code I set up. It's also worth noting that I tried to reproduce the service crashing with other music players and I did not run into the issue at all.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the OS thinks your service is in the background as soon as the user leaves your activity, despite it being a 'foreground' service.

I would design your `MyMusicService` service a bit different though:

1. In `onCreate` prepare the `MediaPlayer`.
2. In the `onStart` or `onStartCommand` implementation of your service, start playing the selected/appropriate sound file. Acquire a partial wake_lock if you want music to keep playing in the background, even if device is asleep. Return `START_STICKY`.
3. Add notification to status bar.
   3 In `onDestroy`, clean everything up.

When the music stops, either by user interaction or when the song ends, be sure to remove notification and release wake lock.

A nice tutorial can be found here.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcb99u8Nlgs&list=PL14AA2548E3C96B50

**Update after OP added comments/updated 'gist':**

I see that the `onReceive` of your `BroadcastReceiver` `mReceiver` in your service accesses a database. This could be the issue.  Off-load this to an `IntentService`: In the `onReceive`, just start an `IntentService` using the same `Intent` that the `onReceive` received. Then the `IntentService` can do all the actual work and not worry about any possible slow database access causing the killing of the process.

If playing music still needs to work when the device is asleep, be sure to acquire a partial wake lock (and be sure to release it when necessary!).

Comment: I actually am returning START_STICKY during onStartCommand already. As far as onCreate, I do initiate the player, but I can't call prepare yet since the service is started even before music is requested to be played and therefore I don't know the path to which song should I pass. Also, I do add a status bar notification when a song is playing, I am not sure if you peaked at the gist I posted. I will however look into acquiring a wakelock which I didn't think I needed since it did play music in bg for like 30 min periods while I was not using the phone.

Comment: In the 'gist' link, I didn't see any 'onStart' or 'onStartCommand' implementation, that why I asked :)  If you are calling 'startForeground' in the service's onCreate, the partial wake lock is only useful when you want to play even when the device is asleep. The 'startForeground' should've prevented the killing of the service when the device is not asleep. Did you check the implementation of your onReceive method(s) in your Service's broadcast-receivers? They must run quickly; if not, your process may be killed.

Comment: Hi, you are right, I did not include the onStartCommand, I added now as I updated the gist. Also, I call startForeground only when leaving the activity (i.e, when going to home, or another activity), and call stopForeground(true) when resuming. As far as the onReceive, not sure how i can test to see if it runs quickly or not. I added a few bits of the onReceive to the gist

Comment: If you do any database/file/storage/internet access in the onReceive, it is at risk of running too slow.

Comment: I saved the changes until now just in case you want to peek at it. And well, Theoretically, I do database access during onReceive, when I call for a new song to be played. Not sure how else I could potentially change it. Background thread (i.e AsyncTask)?

Comment: Do you happen to know what this means: "Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9"?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, could you check if your mId is the same as your notification's id? Also check it's different than 0, because it will then associate it with the activity's id and die with the activity.

Edit: Also check your code does not use onHandle but onStartCommand.

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly help if you provided more information about your architecture, in particular how your Activity and your Service interact.

Wild guessing of course, but to me it sounds as if your Service has a reference to your Activity. Your Activity is likely to get destroyed as soon as you use a different app.

A few questions.

- Do your service and your Activity run in the same process? (This influences how information between Activity and Service can be shared.)
- Does your Activity class have any variables which the Service tries to access? (They belong in the Application class then, if at all.)

Comment: Yes, they both run on the same process. I tried to do different processes, but the aidl interface just drove me nuts. As far as the accessing, they mostly communicate through intents, say for instance user clicks the play button on the activity, then an broadcast would be sent, which the service catches and plays a song specified on the broadcast's extra. To answer your first question, no, the service doesn't keep a reference to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code, maybe somewhere your destroy your process yourself,like `System.exit(0);`,if you do that,then there will be the log

```
channel '418d09c8    

com.deadpixels.light.player/com.deadpixels.light.player.HomeActivity(server)'
 ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x902-24 06:53:32.602:
 E/InputDispatcher(387): channel '418d09c8 
 com.deadpixels.light.player/com.deadpixels.light.player.HomeActivity (server)'
  ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```